# Java salted password hashing

Tags: java

I am using **[this tutorial](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#javasourcecode)** to implement salted password hashing and would store the hash and salt in database.

### Code:

```
/**
 * Creates the salted hash.
 *
 * @param password
 *            the password
 * @return the map
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static Map<byte[], byte[]> createSaltedHash(String password) {

    Map<byte[], byte[]> saltedHash = new HashMap<byte[], byte[]>();
    byte[] hash = null;
    byte[] salt = null;
    final String PBKDF2_ALGORITHM = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";

    // The following may be changed without breaking existing hashes.
    final int SALT_BYTE_SIZE = 24;
    final int HASH_BYTE_SIZE = 24;
    final int PBKDF2_ITERATIONS = 1000;
    final int ITERATION_INDEX = 0;
    final int SALT_INDEX = 1;
    final int PBKDF2_INDEX = 2;

    SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    salt = new byte[SALT_BYTE_SIZE];
    secureRandom.nextBytes(salt);
    //byte[] hash = pbkdf2(password, salt, PBKDF2_ITERATIONS, HASH_BYTE_SIZE);

    PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt,
            PBKDF2_ITERATIONS, (HASH_BYTE_SIZE * 8));
    try {
        SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory
                .getInstance(PBKDF2_ALGORITHM);
        hash = skf.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("HASH:" + hash); // Store this in DB
    System.out.println("SALT:" + salt); // Store this in DB
    saltedHash.put(hash, salt);
    return saltedHash;
}
```

### Question:

Why is it that on changing the password string, the salt and hash values remain unchanged?

Comment: The salt seems to be null, as is the salted hash - it's not being set.

Comment: You're printing arrays. That is not their content, it's just the default `toString()` implementation.

Comment: @doublesharp I modified the code to initialize `saltedHash`, but the output is still the same.

@RealSkeptic - What do I need to do then?

Comment: Try `System.out.println("HASH:" + Arrays.toString(hash) )`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You should use :

```
System.out.println("HASH:" + Arrays.toString(hash)); // Store this in DB
System.out.println("SALT:" + Arrays.toString(salt)); // Store this in DB
```

Comment: @Sandeep with : System.out.println("HASH:" + hash); you're not printing content of your array but you are printing the hexadecimal value of the array

Answer (score 2):

I tried your last code and I see that each time `hash` and `salt` have new values.

Use `Arrays.toString` to dump values, you'll see that both values change:

```
    System.out.println("HASH:" + Arrays.toString( hash ) ); // Store this in DB
    System.out.println("SALT:" + Arrays.toString( salt ) ); // Store this in DB
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to print the byte array as a string...

Using Apache Commons [Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/archives/1.10/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html) to print the contents of the **byte[]**

```
System.out.println( String.format("HASH : %s", Hex.encodeHexString( hash ) ));
System.out.println( String.format("SALT : %s", Hex.encodeHexString( salt ) ));
```